# Angular 2 & Electron offline data

Tags: mysql, laravel, angular, electron

So, I'll be working on an Electron app that uses Angular2 as main front-end tool. 
My back end is running Laravel with MySQL and OAuth2.

There will also be an Android app that communicates with the back end.

The app should be offline first (1 sync a month worst case) but will be used on a daily basis. I'm looking for a best practice to keep the data stored with Electron/Angular2 and have a way to sync this with the back-end.

I found some tools like PouchDB and LocalForage but they don't seem applicable for me. Should I look into creating a sync feature myself? Or are there any other options to consider?

Thanks

Comment: You can use LocalForage and then you create own sync feature on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this has already been a while but I completed this project successfully 5 months ago.

I completed it by writing my own sync functions and storing everything using ng2-webstorage. This was very easy to use with Angular 2.